# Retrieving Azure artifacts recent version from the azure feed

Tags: azure-artifacts

I am looking for an option, how to identify the version of artifact which is being stored in azure devops artifactory. Can someone please throw light on this.

Also i need to push artifact from 1 subscription (example ASubscrip) to another subscription (BSubscrip).
BSubscrip is obviously more strict in terms of security as PROD is being configured there, however our builds are done only on ASubScrip. 
Hence I need to come up with a logic that if version available in BSubscrip is lower than version of ASubScrip, then only trigger the copy pipeline from ASubScrip to BSubScrip.

Please advise how it can be done via pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to perform the operation with the help of below set of commands.

$response = invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://feeds.dev.azure.com/{Org}/{Project name}/_apis/packaging/Feeds//

The response would be json object and required property can be referred $response.versions.version

Please note that while reviewing the output of response object, my focus was only to retrieve version parameter and above approach helped me to get it.

Also note here TOKEN is PAT and there we need to perform some transformation as well.

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($pat)"))